# Unable to print Swedish Characters using DocFlavor

Tags: java

i am trying to print Swedish character using DocFlavor, but i am unable to do it.

My printer only supports below Flavors.

```
Win32 Printer : V2PRINTER supports :
    image/gif; class="[B"
    image/gif; class="java.io.InputStream"
    image/gif; class="java.net.URL"
    image/jpeg; class="[B"
    image/jpeg; class="java.io.InputStream"
    image/jpeg; class="java.net.URL"
    image/png; class="[B"
    image/png; class="java.io.InputStream"
    image/png; class="java.net.URL"
    application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Pageable"
    application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Printable"
    application/octet-stream; class="[B"
    application/octet-stream; class="java.net.URL"
    application/octet-stream; class="java.io.InputStream"
```

Below is code snippet

```
            psStream = new FileInputStream("C:\temp.txt"); 
        DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;   
        Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null);
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();   
        try 
        {
            DocPrintJob job = printer.createPrintJob();
            job.print(myDoc, aset);
            psStream.close();
        }
```

Please let me know if anybody has face same issue and has solution, i dont want to use Graphics2d classes because of printer performance issue.

Thanks in Advance.
Ravi

Comment: Hi, I know that this was 10 years ago but have you ever solved this problem? If you remember.